# Click make active and load the page that the link was pointing to

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function() {
 $('a:first-child').addClass('active');
    $('a').click(function() {
 $('.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
nav a {
 color:#333;
 background:#186467;
 padding:10px;
}
.active {
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<a href="index.html">HOME</a>
<a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
<a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

Guys when i click a it points me the link i want , but active doesnt work.Active "HOME" remains.

And if i add preventDefault() page doesnt point the link.

Comment: It seems to work fine

Comment: Yah i dont  understand why and where is missing..

Comment: What is not working for you? I see that when we click on the link it does turn white and redirects to the page.

Comment: Clicking on a anchor make browser redirect to specific page regarding `href` attribute, so...

Comment: @SandeepNayak after redirection he wants that menu item to be active, i guess... Which is usually handled at server side, or in SPAs

Comment: When i click other link  doesnt remain active  just being active when i click and "HOME" remains active.

Comment: A yea , so there is no solution with jquery? @TJ

Comment: @BurakErman Can you clearly explain your expected behaviour? If you call your snippet on  each page, then how would you expect it to work differently???

Comment: @BurakErman You could set `active` class to specific anchor depending `window.location.pathname` on page load or handle it differently using ajax to load other pages

Comment: Okay now i understand ,  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in , i find out the answer;

```
var path = window.location.href;
$('a').each(function() {
    if (this.href === path) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```